# Android Cannot create floating menu

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to create a floating menu based on a list, e.g. click an item on the list, a menu with 2 options: "Edit" and "Delete" will appear. But I can't get the floating menu. Could anybody help? Thank you so much.

in MainActivity.java:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        data = new ArrayList();
        data.add("Submit a survey");
        data.add("Book Karaoke");
        data.add("Apply VISA");
        data.add("Review Notes");
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this,
                android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,
                data
        );
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.TaskList);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        this.registerForContextMenu(lv);
}

 @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_context, menu);

    }
```

in menu_context.xml

```
<item android:id="@+id/menu_Del"
    android:orderInCategory="100"

    android:title="Del"/>

<item android:id="@+id/menu_Edit"
    android:orderInCategory="200"

    android:title="Edit"/>
```

Comment: it's long click, not a simple click

Comment: @Blackbelt Oh yes it's a long click. Thank you